# Crop an image without specifying the coordinates using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am trying to crop the image with only the area that is useful for processing. However cropping the image by providing the coordinates will not be efficient since the images that I am trying to process have the useful information starting from different coordinates. I was using a `blob_doh()` to detect the blobs so I tried using the min and max of both x and y coordinates to obtain the image with useful information however it seems that it is taking the whole image again.

```
  blobs = blob_doh(binary_image,min_sigma=0.65,threshold=.0325)
  minx = min(blobs[1])
  miny = min(blobs[0])
  maxx = max(blobs[1])
  maxy = max(blobs[1])
  image_split(image_path, int(minx), int(miny), int(maxx), int(maxy))
```

```
def image_split(image_path, int(minx), int(miny), int(maxx), int(maxy)):
  # Reading image
  img = cv2.imread(image_path,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
  y,x = img[:,:,3].nonzero() # get the nonzero alpha coordinates
  minx = np.min(x)
  miny = np.min(y)
  maxx = np.max(x)
  maxy = np.max(y)
  # crop the image
  cropImg = img[miny:maxy, minx:maxx]
  #cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", cropImg)
  print("cropped image")
  #imshow(cropImg)
  cv2_imshow(cropImg)
```

This is what I get after executing the above code.

[image]

But what I rather trying to accomplish is as below

[image]

Any helpful suggestions are welcome. Thank you

After fixing the code, able to fix the crop the image however, the image gets cropped too much.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay so multiple things are going on here that may suggest why you get errors.

In image split you take arguments `xmin`, `xmax` `...` but you don't use them for anything, instead you just define them again using `np.min` and `np.max` - this seems wrong. You already have found the coordinates of the "minimal" blob.

Also when you define your minx, miny ... you mistakenly use blobs[1] for the minx instead of blobs[0].

Finally I think blobs is a list, meaning you should not take min and max of the elements in the list. I dont know what `blob_doh` returns, but assuming its an `x` and a `y` and maybe a `radius` i would do this instead, slicing the list on the first axis:

```py
# Extract x and y coordinates
x_coordinates = blobs[:, 1] 
y_coordinates = blobs[:, 0]

# Get min and max values
minx = np.min(x_coordinates)
maxx = np.max(x_coordinates)
miny = np.min(y_coordinates)
maxy = np.max(y_coordinates)
```

Then fix the code for image_split:

```py
def image_split(image_path, minx, miny, maxx, maxy):
    # Reading image
    img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    
    # Crop the image using provided coordinates
    cropImg = img[miny:maxy+1, minx:maxx+1]  # +1 to include the last pixel
    
    # Uncomment the following line if you want to save the cropped image
    # cv2.imwrite("cropped.png", cropImg)
    
    print("cropped image")
    imshow(cropImg)
```

Hope this works out for you, or at least showed you some errors in your code!

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems to crop the image after fixing the code as you directed. However it crops the image too much. I included the image in the problem description.

Comment: You can add a "padding" parameter to your image_split code, and use that instead of the `+1` i used. It depends on the radius of your blob code, which i can't see.

Comment: for blob in blobs:
      y, x, r = blob
this is how I can access each dot (blob) where x,y are coordinates and r is the radius

Comment: You could slice the radius, and take the largest of those, to use as a padding in the worst-case scenario.

Comment: Also from your image, its impossible to see what happens, because you seem to be showing the image, inside another plot. Look at the x-axis for the image

Comment: Are you mixing matplotlib code with cv2 code?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Kindly ignore the previous comment. But the image gets cropped too much.

Comment: Did you flip x and y coordinates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255265/discussion-between-priyanka-rajendran-and-nicolai-lolansen).